# My dracaena is turning brown in one month what should i do?

Tags: plant-care, leaves, indoors, watering, dracaena

I bought this plant 1 month ago. Leaves are turning brown, faded and plae. What should i do? I have placed it in my bedroom. [image]

Comment: What's it potted in? Sand? It looks almost like concrete.